# Block scoping of let and for…of

Tags: javascript, firefox, ecmascript-6

The [`let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) statement in ES2015 allows us to declare block scope variables, so that for example the following code does what we want:

```
let fs = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    fs.push(() => i);
}
console.log(fs.map(f => f())); // 0, 1, 2
```

However, it does not seem to work **in Firefox** with the [`for…of` loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) which iterates over iterable objects. Here, the block scope is ignored, and we get the same result as if we used `var` instead:

```
fs = [];
let nums = [0, 1, 2];
for (let i of nums) {
    fs.push(() => i);
}
console.log(fs.map(f => f())); // 2, 2, 2
```

Why is the behavior of `let` not working here, and what’s internally so different about the `for…of` loop that this breaks?

Comment: Which environment are you using? Seems like a bug to me.

Comment: using babel's repl, both work out to `0,1,2` https://babeljs.io/repl/

Comment: Oh, then this apparently is a Firefox bug.

Comment: seems to work correctly in node.js 4.2.1 as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others pointed out in the comments, this broken behavior seems to be specific to Firefox, and the code is working properly in other environments (e.g. V8/Node).

As such, I have created a [bug report](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1233089) for it. I’ll update this answer as I learn something new from the Firefox team.

---

This bug has been fixed around August last year and has since landed in the central codebase. The fix is now included in the [Firefox 51 release](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox/Releases/51#JavaScript) that had its final release on January 24th, 2017.

I’m using the Firefox Nightly preview versions and it has been working there properly for a while.