# Why is let singled out in the for-of specification?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, specifications

Part of [the specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-for-in-and-for-of-statements-static-semantics-early-errors) for the `for-of` statement contains the line:

> It is a Syntax Error if the BoundNames of *ForDeclaration* contains "**let**".

In my eyes, it means you can't write:

```
for (var let of someObject) { /* ... */ }
```

But you also get a syntax error for other reserved words, such as:

```
for (var function of someObject) { /* ... */ }
```

or

```
for (let for of someObject) { /* ... */ }
```

To be clear, `let` itself is [perfectly valid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34317339/block-scoping-of-let-and-for-of) to be used to *declare* variables here.
What's special about `let` that means it's singled out in the specification here, or is my interpretation of this line incorrect?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because `let` is officially not a [keyword](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-reserved-words):

> In [strict mode code](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-strict-mode-code), `let` and `static` are treated as reserved keywords through static semantic restrictions (see [12.1.1](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-identifiers-static-semantics-early-errors), [13.3.1.1](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-let-and-const-declarations-static-semantics-early-errors), [13.7.5.1](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-for-in-and-for-of-statements-static-semantics-early-errors), and [14.5.1](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-class-definitions-static-semantics-early-errors)) rather than the lexical grammar.

I can't tell you *why* they decided to do it this way though.

Comment: Right, so if I go digging through the spec, I'm likely to find `let` mentioned in many other places in this fashion?

Comment: At least the ones mentioned in the quote.

Comment: They needed it to be backwards-compatible and not break `var let = 5; alert(let);` and stuff.

Comment: @Bergi: that's what is thought but if I read correctly then `var let = ...;` is now invalid in strict mode. Not sure this was already the case before though.

Comment: @FelixKling: yes, that's what I meant. They were already [reserved words in ES5 strict mode](http://es5.github.io/#x7.6.1.2)

Comment: @Bergi: ah ok. Still wondering why they don't just extend the reserved words in strict mode instead of treating them explicitly differently in rules.